# How to use a resource icon for Delphi JumpList icon

Tags: delphi, icons, taskbar

I have a `TJumpList` in my Delphi application, which is a single EXE. I would like to use icons saved to the app's resources as JumpList icons.

`TJumpList` only accept a `TFileName` string for the icon's path.

Is there any way to use a resource icon in this way, without having external icon files, or extracting resources externally at runtime?

I have tried to load from resource, but it seems it only accepts a string which is a path to an icon file.

Comment: If it will *only accept a TFileName*, and you *tried to load from resource but it only accepts a string which is a path to an icon*, haven't you already answered your own question? *only accept a TFileName* seems pretty plain and clear.

Comment: I said it seems it only accepts a string as I am only using visual designer but that doesn't mean there is not some other workaround which is why I asked the question. I know it's possible in C so could be possible in Delphi using custom class or wrapper. My Delphi is not advanced so was hoping for a workaround to keep my application as a single portable EXE

Comment: Did you read the TJumpList documentation, or check the source code? Did you check and see if the icons were actually needed after you build your application (by building, then moving the files, then running your app outside the IDE)? That test could be done in a couple of minutes using a new blank VCL app and a TJumpList on the form.

Comment: Testing the app after build is not possible because i want to change the jumplist icons on the fly depending on the file extensions so changing the icon at runtime will try to link to external file. Yes I checked the source and it requires TFileName as I stated but other image components are also the same which can be loaded from imagelist or resource but I don't know how to do it for jumplist or if it is possible in Delphi

Comment: The documentation for TJumpList indicates that the only way to assign the icon is to provide a path and filename. There is nothing else that I can see that would allow you to load one otherwise.

Comment: Just a thought. You can save the image as a file from the resource and then just provide the path to that file you save. After ut's loaded just delete the file again. I know this is not ideal but looking at the comment and the Answer Remy gave it seems this might be your only option for now.

Comment: Adriaan: This is what I ended up doing which was fine for normal static jumplist tasks, but because I also use 'ShowRecent' which are created dynamically, I couldn't delete the files straight away, and they needed to remain for the whole app session, so I now delete them on app close as a temporary solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, [`TJumpListItem`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.JumpList.TJumpListItem) uses the Win32 [`IShellLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw) COM interface. That interface does not support using an icon via a resource, only via a file path.

However, that interface *does* allow for specifying an icon index within an executable (EXE or DLL) file.  But, `TJumpListItem` is hard-coded to always use index 0, no matter what kind of file is being used.  There is already an open ticket about that:

[RSP-21558: IconResourceIndex not avalaible in TJumpListItem (TJumpList)](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21558)

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer as solved and hope they fix it...

Incidentally I just discovered another bug in the Delphi TJumpList. On Windows 10, if you have the setting 'Settings->Personalization->Start->Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar' set to OFF and your TJumpList has AutoRefresh Enabled and you have a TJumpListItem in CustomCategories then on application start it raises an exception "JumpListItem exception: Error -2147024891: Adding a custom category ('') and its child items to a new jump list." which pretty much makes CustomCategories useless